# How to build a custom docker image which enables the connection of Apache Databricks with Denodo?

Tags: docker, databricks, docker-machine, denodo, databricks-community-edition

For now we are giving all the configurations manually in the Databricks to connect to denodo database.Now the issue is we need to have a docker image which can enable the connection so that a new user doesnt have to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set this up in a Docker container and, once ready, you can create a Docker image based on the contents of the container. Follow this instructions: https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/create-docker-image/